# 4 Monitor Extended Desktop MoBo Graphics Combination

Tags: linux, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard

I need to put together a 4-monitor extended desktop setup for non-gaming purposes. All 4 monitors are supposed to display at 1920X1080. Any suggestions as to what motherboard/graphics card combination would be the cheapest and still be the best solution to my needs?

This is my precise requirement: for a research project in human cognition and learning we want need to display 16 pdf pages(4 pages per monitor) at once for a single second to our research subjects.

I've been told the optimal solution would be a combination of :
(i) a MoBo with integrated graphics having two monitor-ports, and,
(ii)an add-on PCIE graphics card having two monitor ports.

I need to know whether such a configuration( viz. 2 monitors plugged into the integrated graphics card and another 2 monitors plugged into the other graphics card) would work and will it be economically viable.
If yes, what MoBo/Graphics card combination would you recommend?
If no, what are my other options?

P.S.- Linux friendly MoBo and Graphics Card would be nice.

Comment: I had an Nvidia graphics card laying around so through it in my PC. I do know it couldn't use both integrated and the graphics card at the same time. I believe this is just because they were different brands as I know I've heard of people using them at the same time. Just something to look out for as you build this. I would say using two matching cards as tetsujin mentioned would be safest.

Comment: As I read somewhere, It's *only* because most MoBos assign the discrete graphics as "primary" and disable the on-board graphics from BIOS. Once, you reassign the on-board one as "primary" from BIOS, it works. I'll post the link when I'm able to get it again. (As far as I remember it was from some "respectable' website) You might try and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to try something like a matched pair of NVidia 210's. They are really cheap these days, maybe 20 £/$/€ each, low power consumption & can do 2 x 2560x1440 each. They are obviously not any good for gaming, but for simple 2D imagery they are fine, fanless & therefore silent, too.

Comment: The NVdia site (http://www.nvidia.in/object/product_geforce_210_in.html) says: " Maximum Digital Resolution= "2560X1600. Does that mean 2560x1600 per display? Or will it get divided by 2?

Comment: per display - so long as you avoid the VGA port you should be fine.

Comment: no advertising intended, but this caught my eye on Google http://www.amazon.com/MSI-Computer-Corp-PCI-Express-N210-512D2/dp/B009K1PY3S with 2xDVI a user comment about using 2x2k res... though only in 16-bit colour & several mentioned success on nix. I'd suggest some more googling before purchase, but as a starter...

Comment: Since the graphics engine is Nvidia, it's expected to be Linux-friendly. I couldn't find MSI make but there are Gigabyte and Asus cards based upon Nvidia 210. And yes, they're cheap.

Assuming that Nvidia 210 is what I'll go for, do you suggest 
(a) a MoBo with on-board graphics supporting dual (extended-desktop) monitor-coupled with one 210
(b)a MoBo with two PCIe graphics port to put two Nvidia 210s?
The cheaper, the better.
 
For eg. Intel DH77EB has on-board dual monitor support but can incorporate only one discrete graphics.
Thanks for your help so far. :)

Comment: I'm beyond my knowledge-base really, but I'm not sure if any given mobo can run onboard & discreet graphics simultaneously. At least you'd know with 2 discreet cards that it ought to work, but I'd hesitate to push you specifically in either direction.

Comment: As I read somewhere, It's *only* because most MoBos assign the discrete graphics as "primary" and disable the on-board graphics from BIOS. Once, you reassign the on-board one as "primary" from BIOS, it works. I'll post the link when I'm able to get it again. (As far as I remember it was from some "respectable' website)

Comment: do you know of any such dirt-cheap nvidia cards doing 3 monitor outputs? *getting greedier* :)